# Cálculos de Campos SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Como puedo calcular 2 campos o mas y estos sean arrojado a un campo como resultado final, y que los demás registro que agregue se calculen automático en el campo ya creado.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow en español! Bienvenido Angel Gomez a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un nuevo campo a la tabla (en SSMS), y  observa sus propiedades (propiedades de la columna), verás una propiedad denominada "Especificación de columna calculada" ahí puedes poner la fórmula que desees, por ejemplo `campo1+campo2`.

También admite funciones propias de SQL Server (Substring, GetDate(), Left, etc.).

Cuando se inserten nuevos registros, el valor del campo se insertará (representará) de forma automática.